# Convert .avi to video dvd on linux commandline

Tags: linux, command-line, video-processing

I have some .avi files. I want to convert them into video dvd images, which will be burnable into dvds, which will be playable by any commercial dvd player. Is there a simple command for this?

The first step of the conversion seems a little bit problematic to me. Mencoder probably can't do this (at least the created images aren't playable in my dvd player).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this out?
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-create-video-dvds.html

dvdauthor should do it.